# Understanding Alamofire's Response Object Serialization use of Closures

Tags: swift, serialization, alamofire

I'm trying to understand the below example taken from this [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87595/intermediate-alamofire-tutorial). My main confusion is not with *what* (de-serializes JSON data into your own object in a convenient manner) it's doing but *how* it's doing it. What I'll do is explain the code snippet as I understand it but my confusion stems from the completionHandler closure and it's type definition. I'll highlight that after my initial take on what the code does.

First the snippet with line numbers:

```
  1 @objc public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
  2   init(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
  3 }
  4
  5 extension Alamofire.Request {
  6   public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
  7     let serializer: Serializer = { (request, response, data) in
  8       let JSONSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
  9       let (JSON: AnyObject?, serializationError) = JSONSerializer(request, response, data)
 10       if response != nil && JSON != nil {
 11         return (T(response: response!, representation: JSON!), nil)
 12       } else {
 13         return (nil, serializationError)
 14       }
 15     }
 16
 17     return response(serializer: serializer, completionHandler: { (request, response, object, error) in
 18       completionHandler(request, response, object as? T, error)
 19     })
 20   }
 21 }
```

Line 6 - Here we declare a generic function (responseObject) that accepts a "completionHandler" closure with a signature of `(NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, NSError?) -> Void`. It then returns an instance of it's own class `-> self`.

Lines 7 to 15 - Here we declare a closure using the `Serializer` signature. This does the actual work of turning JSON into the appropriate class conforming to the ResponseObjectSerializable protocol.

Lines 17 to 19 - Here we call the "response()" method in the Alamofire.Request class (I think?) passing in the previously defined serializer closure. What we also pass in is an *actual* completionHandler closure that then calls some other, mysterious completionHandler method. The result of this "response()" method call is returned to the client code.

I feel I understand it to the point where in the "completionHandler" closure  is passed as an argument on line 17. But then we call some other "completionHandler" - where is it defined? Or is it calling itself?

Also, how are we referring to the serializer on line 17 when it was created seemingly out of scope on line 7?

Comment: No, line 18 is calling `completionHandler` closure passed as an argument to `responseObject<...` on line 6.

Lines 17-19 return `response` with *intermediate* closure which just calls `completionHandler` closure passed on line 6 and it passes same arguments as it receives with one exception - it tries to cast `object` to `T` before it will be passed to `completionHandler` (line 6).

Comment: That makes it much clearer, thanks. Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Did it, enhanced it little bit, so, it can be treated as an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't understand it, just get your original code ...

```
  1 @objc public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
  2   init(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
  3 }
  4
  5 extension Alamofire.Request {
  6   public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
  7     let serializer: Serializer = { (request, response, data) in
  8       let JSONSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
  9       let (JSON: AnyObject?, serializationError) = JSONSerializer(request, response, data)
 10       if response != nil && JSON != nil {
 11         return (T(response: response!, representation: JSON!), nil)
 12       } else {
 13         return (nil, serializationError)
 14       }
 15     }
 16
 17     return response(serializer: serializer, completionHandler: { (request, response, object, error) in
 18       completionHandler(request, response, object as? T, error)
 19     })
 20   }
 21 }
```

... remove *irrelevant* parts or collapse them like this ...

```
  5 extension Alamofire.Request {
  6   public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
  7     let serializer: Serializer = { ... }
 16
 17     return response(serializer: serializer, completionHandler: {
 18       ...
 19     })
 20   }
 21 }
```

... and expand collapsed parts one by one when you get an idea what it is doing.

So, what's there ...

`completionHandler` on line 6 - first argument to the `public func responseObject<...` function. It's a closure and you can pass it around or use it (execute it). Here's the Apple docs quote:

> Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed
>   around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks
>   in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.

If you do want to use closure (execute it), you can use it as a function like this:

```
completionHandler(pass arguments, to, this closure, here)
```

If you want to pass it around, just use argument name `completionHandler`.

[Closures & Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

`completionHandler` on line 17 - second argument for `func response`. And here we're passing closure with functionality defined on line 18 (collapsed now). This closure can be used inside `response` function and referenced there by argument name `completionHandler`. But only inside `response` function, it's for this function. So, let's expand it ...

```
  5 extension Alamofire.Request {
  6   public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
  7     let serializer: Serializer = { ... }
 16
 17     return response(serializer: serializer, completionHandler: {
 18       completionHandler(request, response, object as? T, error)
 19     })
 20   }
 21 }
```

What happens now ...

1. Inside `response` function, closure we're passing on lines 17-19 can be passed around or used.
2. When it happens, body of this closure is executed (line 18).
3. Body of closure uses another closure, which was passed as an argument to function `responseObject`.

To make it shorter ... When `response` executes `completionHandler` closure (lines 17-19), this closure executes another closure (line 18), which was passed as an argument to function `responseObject...` (line 6).

Hope it makes it clear. It's not that hard, just learn how to skip some parts of the code when analysing it (collapse it in your mind).